# Bibliography and headers with titleps and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, titleps

I am using `titleps` to get custom headers, and `biblatex` for the bibliography. The headers look all right except when it comes to the bibliography, where a "REFERENCES" label appears in the header and footer. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{fancy}{ 
\headrule
\sethead[\normalsize \thepage][][]
{Author}{Document}{\normalsize \thepage}
\setfoot[][][]{}{}{}
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2013,
author = {Author, A},
title = {A nice paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2013},
volume = {1},
pages = {1--2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1]
\cite{A2013}   
\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image]

The left page is ok but not the right page. Where does the "REFERENCES" label come from?

Note that this does not happen if I use `bibtex` instead of `biblatex` for the bibliography, or `fancyhdr` instead of `titleps` to customize the headers. For instance, replacing lines 3-9 in the example with

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{Document}
\fancyhead[L]{Author}
\fancyhead[R]{\normalsize \thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

gives the expected output:
[image]

How can I obtain the same result with `titleps` and `biblatex`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For some reasons, `titleps` reacts to `\markboth` commands in an apparently arbitrary way. You solve the issue by avoiding the `\markboth`: add

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\section*{#1}}
```

to your preamble after having loaded `biblatex`.

---

Note that the usual definition for the default bib heading style is

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

and we simply avoid issuing `\markboth`.

In the documentation of `titleps` there are two mentions of `\markboth`, saying that it should be avoided when using page styles defined with the package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not the first time that I have trouble understanding how `titleps` deals with marks. The advice on trying to avoid them altogether is probably good.

Comment: Another possibility is to define a new heading and after to use it. For example: \defbibheading{mybiblio}[\refname{\section*{#1}\markboth{}{}} and then \printbibliography[heading=mybiblio]

Comment: I had the same problem, and with the above solution I was receiving 'undefined control sequence \defbibheading'. But applying https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336303/259895 fixed the issue.