# page number, bookmark number, do not match

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, bookmarks

Good day people,

Today, I was wondering how to correlate the bookmark numbering with the table of contents. As the attached picture shows, the **Titulo** and **Declaracion** share the same number page at the bookmark part. In the documento, **Declaracion** correspond to ***i*** (Roman number for one). I have try several combinations of commands and I'm still getting the same result.

The header of main tex file is:

```
\documentclass[
        twoside,
%            openright,
        titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,
        footinclude=true,
        abstractoff,
    dottedtoc,
        cleardoublepage=empty,
        BCOR=5mm, paper=a4, fontsize=12pt,
        listof=totoc,
        ]{scrreprt}
\PassOptionsToPackage{
            eulerchapternumbers,
            listings,
            pdfspacing,
            subfig,
            beramono,
            parts}{classicthesis}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\deftripstyle{pgnumbottomcenter}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark{}}{}
\pagestyle{pgnumbottomcenter}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumbottomcenter}
\usepackage[spanish,german,english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand*{\appendixname}{Ap\'endice}}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\setlength{\textwidth}{176mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{250mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{5mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{5mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{4.6mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{4.6mm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0mm}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-5mm}
%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
%\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
% \usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epigraph}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title, titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Ap\'endices}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Ap\'endices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Ap\'endices}
% workaround
%\makeatletter
%\appto{\appendices}{\def\Hy@chapapp{Appendix}}
%\makeatother
%\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{1ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{1ex}{1ex}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
%\deftripstyle{pgnumbottomcenter}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark{}}{}
%\pagestyle{pgnumbottomcenter}
%\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumbottomcenter}
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\include{FrontBackmatter/Titlepage}
\include{FrontBackmatter/Titleback}
\cleardoublepage
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\pagestyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Declaration}
\end{document}
```

The header of **Declaration.tex** file is:

```
%*******************************************************
% Declaration
%*******************************************************
%\refstepcounter{dummy}
%\clearpage
%\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{Declaraci\'on}{declaraci\'on}
\chapter*{Declaraci\'on}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Thank so much in advance for any clue and have a good day

[image]

Comment: Do you have/want `Declaracion` in the ToC as well? If not, I would uncomment the `\cleardoublepage`, which may be the source of your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: thank @Werner, I did it and I'm still getting the same output : (

Comment: So, the MWE...?

Comment: ok @cfr, I update what I understood about MWE

Comment: @Alejandro: Your 'MWE' is far from being minimal **and** working ;-)

Comment: Special hint from my side, drop `classicthesis`. This won't be the last oddity you encounter.

Comment: `fancyhdr` should not be used with a KOMAclass, as well as `titlesec` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224331/customize-koma-section-headings-without-titlesec/224334#224334). Du you want your declaration in the toc as well? If so, use `\addchap`.

Comment: You should use the Koma facilities to set up the page layout as well, rather than setting the dimensions manually. (If absolutely necessary, you can override Koma and use `geometry`, which is better than manually, but less good than using Koma if that's possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the code in the question is contradictory, I can only give a partial answer. The image contains chapters, which are not part of the code. The table of contents does have page numbers usually, but the bookmarks do not have page numbers. If a bookmark is inner document link, then it could point to a wrong page, but this is not stated in the question. And there could be wrong PDF page labels.

The file `Declaration.tex` contains:

```
%\clearpage
%\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{Declaraci\'on}{declaraci\'on}
\chapter*{Declaraci\'on}
```

`\chapter` usually starts a new page (`\cleardoublepage`). The anchor setting (`\phantomsection`) and bookmark (`\pdfbookmark`) are used before. Thus it can happen that they go to a previous page. This is solved by removing the comment character in front of `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[1]{Declaraci\'on}{declaracion}% no need for funny anchor names
\chapter*{Declaraci\'on}
```

`\phantomsection` is not needed, because `\pdfbookmark` already creates an anchor.