# koma-script: How to make chapter title span text width?

Tags: koma-script, scrbook

Considering this code, how to make chapter title continue smoothly under the word `CHAPTER 1:` spanning the whole `\textwidth`?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[chapterprefix=off]{scrbook}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{CHAPTER~\thechapter:\enskip}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Some long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible with a simple command.

[image: diaabiidouScrbookChapterlayout]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{CHAPTER~\thechapter:\enskip}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{#2#3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{I am sorry to say that no wombats and no ducks can be
found in the following text}
\chapter{Some long long long long long long long long long
long long title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me the meaning of `\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{#2#3}`? since I couldn't understand it from the manual.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou The default sets the command to do what you see, the title *hangs* next to the chapter word (does not flow underneath it). With renewing that, and *not* telling LaTeX to do the former, the result is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your previous explanation. I would be grateful if you could consider my question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341552/2288) about removing indentation of ToC section entries.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Huge\bfseries}{CHAPTER~\thechapter:}{0.5em}{}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Some long long long long long long long long long long long title}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I need the same output, but, unfortunately, the incompatibility between `titlesec` and `koma-script` prevented me from depending on this approach.