# Bibliography unwanted header and footer

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, header-footer

I am trying to add the bibliography into my TOC.

The problem is as soon as I add [heading=bibintoc] to it, all bibliography pages will have a "BIBLIOGRAPHY" header and footer.

How can I remove this header and footer, keep the section title (Bibliography) in the beginning of the first page of the bibliography and have it listed in the TOC?

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, 
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblo01.bib}

\linespread{1}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]
```

Comment: Well, those settings may interact with whatever you're doing to set your headers and footers, but you haven't shared that information with us so it's rather hard to guess which of the many possibilities apply in your case. Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Since with `bibintoc` more or less what you get is a `\section*` (or `\chapter*`) `biblatex` also sets `\markboth{#1}{#1}` for the correct header, if you don't want that you need to modify the `\defbibheading{bibintoc}`. In order to make sure everything works out we need to see an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), as we don't know the document class you are using and any other packages that might influence headers and footers.

Comment: Any news here? In order to be able to provide useful answers we would need to see what document class you use, what additional things you do to your section/chapter headings and most importantly what you would the final output to be like.

Comment: @moewe I guess this question is somehow duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89884/18401.