# Bad interaction between titlesec/titleps and packages that use \markboth internally

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, titlesec, debugging, titleps

The following MWE demonstrates a bad interaction between `endfloat` and `titleps`.  The second page has the word FIGURES in all caps in both the header and the footer, contrary to the page style specification.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[heads,nolists]{endfloat}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead{}{}{\thepage}
  \setfoot{}{}{}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{main}
\section{Foo}
\section*{Bar}
\begin{figure}
  Blurf
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`biblatex` is also affected: in this case REFERENCES appears in both the footer and the header.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique Générale},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Year = {1995},
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{main}{
\setfoot{My footer}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\cite{Saussure1995}
\kant[1-2]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have traced this to `endfloat` and `biblatex` internally using the `\mark` commands.  Specifically, the problem goes away if I redefine `\markboth` to do nothing (still consuming two arguments).  I don't feel particularly safe doing that, though.  At the least I'd like to know whether anything else needs the same treatment, and what might break.

The titleps documentation warns that "using `\markboth` can lead to unpredictable results", but that's a disappointing cop-out when it's a documented interface that packages think they can use.

Suggestions?

Comment: I was just about to post an identical question regarding `biblatex` and `titleps`, but I'll add a bounty to your question instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn If you have a MWE with biblatex, could you add it?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Bear in mind, that there is also `\markright`.  This could also cause problems.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, I didn't know about `filecontents`.

Comment: Sorry for being dim, but what's a 'nop'?

Comment: @cfr programmer jargon for "a thing that does nothing" (it's originally an abbreviation for "no operation").  I will revise to avoid the term.

Comment: I don't suppose, 'I wouldn't touch `titleps`/`titlesec` with a barge pole` is the kind of answer you and @AlanMunn are looking for, is it?

Comment: @cfr It happens that I solved my immediate problem by not using them anymore, but no, not really ;-)

Comment: @cfr I think the issue is really to do with `titleps` not `titlesec`, since I've only encountered it as I've gradually switched from using `fancyhdr` to `titleps`. And I use `titlesec` in every document I write.

Comment: @AlanMunn It is particularly weird that it *combines* the mark with the specified footer text.

Comment: That said, I don't think Biblatex is blameless here. Why doesn't it leave `\section` or `\chapter` or whatever to set the marks? Presumably because it is unnumbered, but hard-coding the marks based on the current class doesn't seem a good solution.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I agree. My current solution is to redefine `\bibheading` but that's a pain to do all the time.

Comment: We had [Bibliography and headers with titleps and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89884/35864) where the answer was to what you are doing right now. [titleps for fancyhdr users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html) says "you must forget about `\leftmark`, `\rightmark`, `\markboth` and `\markright`, as well as redefining `\sectionmark` and the like." So it seems that the package really isn't compatible with that. Setting the commands.

Comment: We also find `Note |\markboth| is a command to set the |myheadings| marks and here does not make sense. In fact, using it can lead to unpredictable results.` in `titleps.tex`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the links. I didn't manage to find that question.

Comment: @moewe As you may guess from the last sentence of the question, I feel that this *is* a bug in titleps, and I'd be happiest with an answer that *patched titleps* such that the documented `\mark` commands were again compatible with what other packages expect them to do.  (Alan's bounty is of course up to him.)

Comment: It's not a bug - just the one-step mechanism is incompatible with the two-step one. I'll try to minimize problems, but a general solution is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines to the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\let\ttl@titlemarks\relax
\makeatother
```

Then the two examples will work. This also helped in [Customizing titleps' header in index to include current index entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335522/110998).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but too long for a comment.

If and how `\markboth` commands are handled is one part of the question. But in the example the pagestyle is apart from the page number empty and so shouldn't show the content of marking commands. This is clearly a bug and should be reported to the author of titleps. A simple example to demonstrate the problem is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead{}{}{}
  \setfoot{}{}{}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{main}
\mark{abc}
blub
\end{document}
```

It prints "bc" in the header and the footer.

Comment: Interesting that the first "a" is swallowed. Do you think it would be a bad idea to disable `\mark` and friends at the end of loading `titleps` (maybe from within the package)?

Comment: titleps does a "secondoftwo" that's why the first part of the mark is lost (and why in the original question the \rightmark is shown). I have no idea what would be the best solution. It would need much time to understand why titleps does what it does. One should really better contact the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks Ulrike, I've sent a bug report to Javier.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This doesn't work even without `titleps`, as one could expect if a TeX primitive is used instead of LaTeX `\mark...` stuff. LaTeX internally uses a couple of values inside marks (left and right), and you are passing, as far as LaTeX is concerned, three -- a, b and c. Therefore, you'll get bc (or ac, depending on the page) with standard LaTeX, too.

Comment: @JavierBezos The problem is not that one get a faulty or senseless output, but that one get an output at all. The pagestyle is defined as **empty**. So why do a part of the mark content show up? (The problem can be shown with \markboth too, but for debugging I think the primitive command is better).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know the problem and in fact it's documented. My point is this example is wrong even for testing and debugging purposes, because LaTeX doesn't work that way. Just use `\markboth` and it will be fine (I mean, wrongly fine ;-)).

Comment: @JavierBezos Well if you want, you can exchange the \mark with `\markright{abc}`. This will print abc in the header and footer and is imho also a bug.

Comment: @JavierBezos Would it be an option to redefine `\markboth` and friends to just issue a warning from `titleps`? Or is there a "legitimate use" of `\markboth` with `titleps`?

Comment: @moewe Yes, I think the warning is an option, indeed. I'm reading the code in search of inspiration, and I have some ideas I'd like to test.