# Problem headers/footers and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

I've recently fallen upon a problem with biblatex formatting of headers/footers: by default it prints on the even page the word ‘bibliography’ in the left part of the even page header, followed by the page number, and also ‘bibliography’ in the left part of the even page footer. So far so good, even if I don't how to change it.

What is more troublesome is that the same word appears in the rest of my text (index, index of notations, &c.). If I want to get rid of it, I have to use the `empty`or `plain` styles – but not any customised page style (I do that with `titleps`).

I couldn't find in `biblatex` where the pagestyle for bibliographies is coded. Any help is very welcome!

Comment: MWE? Or is it for puzzle.stackexchange.com?

Comment: No, no. I'll have to make one, but  the problem happens with a book project. The book has two rather long personal  style files, and I'll try to extract a minimal compiling code, but I asked in case someone  had met the same type of problem – and had hints.

Comment: As far as I know, `biblatex` does not define page styles for the bibliography, it simply adds a heading (`\section`, `\section*`, `\addsec`, ... what have you) and `\markboth`. As you will find in [Bad interaction between titlesec/titleps and packages that use \markboth internally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292554/35864) and its links, `titleps` doesn't particularly like `\markboth`. See [Bibliography and headers with titleps and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89884/35864) for a solution.

Comment: @Moewe: Thanks for the links. I'll study them carefully.

Comment: Do you think your question is substantially different from the other two?

Comment: No, it is exactly the same problem,and @egreg's solution completely solved my problem. I just had to replace `\section*` with `\chapter*` in the re-definition of `\bibheading`, as I am using the book class. Thanks a lot for these links.

Comment: @Bernard Which one should be close this as a duplicate of?

Comment: @egreg: I really don't see any difference: both questions describe the same phenomenon. Of course, the second link contains your solution. Let me add another observation, which is not in any of posts, as they use the article class: my bibliography is followed by an index of notations, an index and a table of contents (as is traditional in France). The phenomenon affects only the bibliography and the first index (4pages). Afterwards, the customised page style enters in action.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to close your question as a duplicate of the one that already has an answer. As to why this only appears with certain chapters in your document we can only speculate, maybe `\markboth{}{}` is issued somewhere ...

Comment: @moewe: No problem. I'll try to investigate.