# incompatibility between biblatex and titlesec?

Tags: biblatex, titlesec

My goal is to have a separate reference list for each chapter 
and to have custom headers and footers.
For the former I am using `biblatex` and for the latter I am
using `titlesec`. Using the attached tex file, a problem is manifest
on the second page --- the references are corrupting my header
and footer. Either I don't have the correct options or the
there is an incompatibility between the two packages.

Help would be appreciated. All code is from TeX Live 2015. 
My OS is Linux Mint Rosa.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{filecontents}{matrix.bib}
@book{golub.vanloan,
  author    = "Gene Golub and Charles {Van Loan}",
  title     = "Matrix Computations",
  edition   = "4th Edition",
  publisher = "The Johns Hopkins University Press",
  address   = "Baltimore, Maryland",
  year      = "2013",
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibencoding=ascii,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references={Works Cited},}
\addbibresource{matrix.bib} 

\usepackage[explicit,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}                         % command
{\Large\bfseries}                              % format
{Section \thesection\ ---}                     % label
{.5em}                                         % sep
{\filright#1}                                  % before code
%\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\newpagestyle{headingstyle}[\large\sffamily]{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\sectiontitle][][\thesection]% even
          {\thesection}{}{\sectiontitle}% odd
  \setfoot{}{\usepage}{}%
}
\pagestyle{headingstyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\chapter{This is the chapter title.}
\section{A Big Matrix}
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
Golub and VanLoan \cite{golub.vanloan} is a good book.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\newpage
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
%\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{A Little Matrix}
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\newpage
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [Bad interaction between titlesec/titleps and packages that use \markboth internally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292554/35864), [Bibliography and headers with titleps and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89884/35864).

Answer (score 6):

The incompatibility between `titlesec` and `biblatex` is known: see the following text from the `biblatex` manual

> The `titlesec` package redefines user-level document division commands such as `\chapter` or `\section`.  This approach is not compatible with internal command changes applied by the BibLaTeX `refsection` and `refsegment` option settings described in § 3.1.2.1.

Accordingly, you have to look for a different solution. If I have understood correctly what you want, you can redefine the bibliography `bibheading`.

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{#1}}
```

This  definition will use `\section*` to print the `\bibname` and does not save any values in the section marks (so they are no include in the header and footer).  Also, you  have  remove the `heading=subbibliogaphy` from `\printbibliography`.

Answer (score 3):

[Guido's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310140/) provides the right idea, but let's not throw the baby out with the bathwater without exhausting all the infant-preserving options first.

There is no need to switch to plain `\printbibliography`, abandoning `subbibliography`. All that is needed is to redefine the heading for the appropriate bibliography environment. In your case, that's `subbibliography` rather than `bibliography`. And `\refname` is probably more appropriate than `bibname` since people rarely want a bibliography - as opposed to a list of references - per chapter.

[image: redefine subbibliography headings]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{golub.vanloan,
  author    = "Gene Golub and Charles {Van Loan}",
  title     = "Matrix Computations",
  edition   = "4th Edition",
  publisher = "The Johns Hopkins University Press",
  address   = "Baltimore, Maryland",
  year      = "2013",
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[bibencoding=ascii,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references={Works Cited},}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}}
\usepackage[explicit,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}                         % command
{\Large\bfseries}                              % format
{Section \thesection\ ---}                     % label
{.5em}                                         % sep
{\filright#1}                                  % before code
%\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\newpagestyle{headingstyle}[\large\sffamily]{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\sectiontitle][][\thesection]% even
          {\thesection}{}{\sectiontitle}% odd
  \setfoot{}{\usepage}{}%
}
\pagestyle{headingstyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\chapter{This is the chapter title.}
\section{A Big Matrix}
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
Golub and VanLoan \cite{golub.vanloan} is a good book.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\newpage
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
%\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{A Little Matrix}
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\newpage
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their county.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In any case you have to provide a new definition of a `heading`.

Comment: @Guido Oh, I completely agree. I upvoted your answer for precisely this reason ;). But you don't have to abandon the `subbibliography` environment.