# Header title for bibliography is incorrect

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, titlesec

this is the first time I am asking a question on stackexchange and I hope my MWE is helpful: I am working on an assignment in which I want to include a header specifying the current section of each page. However, in the bibliography the header shows the title of the *previous* section and in addition inserts **References** in capital letters. How can I change it to simply show "References"?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}


\newpagestyle{headers}{
\headrule
\sethead{\thesection. \sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}             
\footrule
\setfoot{Author}{}{Institution}
} 

\pagestyle{headers}


\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\Blindtext
\cite{Chandra2014}

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `titlesec` and `biblatex` don't play well. Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310140/29873

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scrlayer-scrpage` would be an alternative to using `titleps`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,headsepline,footsepline]{article} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\usepackage[automark,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection.~}
\ifoot{Carl Capybara}
\ofoot{School of Duck Dancing}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}


\begin{document}

\section{Wombat}
\Blindtext
\cite{aristotle:physics}

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the question is about headers-footers and no features of `titlesec` were present, i decided to give an alternative to `titleps`, which shares the same commands with `titlesec` and the `pagestyles` option.

Answer (score 2):

This is due `\defbibheading` using `\markboth` , which interacts with `titleps`. So I redefined this command (adapted from an answer from @egreg):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{nonsense.bib}


\newpagestyle{headers}{
\headrule
\sethead{\ifthesection{\thesection. }{}\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
\footrule
\setfoot{Author}{}{Institution}
}

\pagestyle{headers}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\section*{#1}\sectionmark{\refname}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\Blindtext
\cite{nonsense}
\nocite{*}
\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]