# Page header/footer in index is incorrect

Tags: header-footer, memoir, imakeidx

(This might be a duplicate of [Header title for bibliography is incorrect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/header-title-for-bibliography-is-incorrect) but I can't make head or tail of that question or its answer.)

Here's my large MCE:

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,oneside,final]{memoir}

% support for indexing
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=book,intoc,columns=1]
\makeindex[name=code,intoc,columns=1,title=Index of code samples]

% support for cross-references (must come after imakeidx)
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\indexbook}[1]{\index[book]{#1}}
\newcommand{\indexcode}[1]{\index[code]{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Call me Ishmael}
\lipsum[1-4]
\indexbook{yuz} \indexbook{zuz} \indexbook{avz} \indexbook{bvz}
\indexbook{cvz} \indexbook{dvz} \indexbook{evz} \indexbook{fvz}
\indexbook{gvz} \indexbook{hvz} \indexbook{ivz} \indexbook{jvz}
\indexbook{kvz} \indexbook{lvz} \indexbook{mvz} \indexbook{nvz}
\indexbook{ovz} \indexbook{pvz} \indexbook{qvz} \indexbook{rvz}
\indexbook{svz} \indexbook{tvz} \indexbook{uvz} \indexbook{vvz}
\indexbook{wvz} \indexbook{xvz} \indexbook{yvz} \indexbook{zvz}
\indexbook{awz} \indexbook{bwz} \indexbook{cwz} \indexbook{dwz}
\indexbook{ewz} \indexbook{fwz} \indexbook{gwz} \indexbook{hwz}
\indexbook{iwz} \indexbook{jwz} \indexbook{kwz} \indexbook{lwz}
\indexbook{mwz} \indexbook{nwz} \indexbook{owz} \indexbook{pwz}
\indexbook{qwz} \indexbook{rwz} \indexbook{swz} \indexbook{twz}
\indexbook{uwz} \indexbook{vwz} \indexbook{wwz} \indexbook{xwz}
\indexbook{ywz} \indexbook{zwz} \indexbook{axz} \indexbook{bxz}
\indexbook{cxz} \indexbook{dxz} \indexbook{exz} \indexbook{fxz}
\indexbook{gxz} \indexbook{hxz} \indexbook{ixz} \indexbook{jxz}

\indexcode{yuz} \indexcode{zuz} \indexcode{avz} \indexcode{bvz}
\indexcode{cvz} \indexcode{dvz} \indexcode{evz} \indexcode{fvz}
\indexcode{gvz} \indexcode{hvz} \indexcode{ivz} \indexcode{jvz}
\indexcode{kvz} \indexcode{lvz} \indexcode{mvz} \indexcode{nvz}
\indexcode{ovz} \indexcode{pvz} \indexcode{qvz} \indexcode{rvz}
\indexcode{svz} \indexcode{tvz} \indexcode{uvz} \indexcode{vvz}
\indexcode{wvz} \indexcode{xvz} \indexcode{yvz} \indexcode{zvz}
\indexcode{awz} \indexcode{bwz} \indexcode{cwz} \indexcode{dwz}
\indexcode{ewz} \indexcode{fwz} \indexcode{gwz} \indexcode{hwz}
\indexcode{iwz} \indexcode{jwz} \indexcode{kwz} \indexcode{lwz}
\indexcode{mwz} \indexcode{nwz} \indexcode{owz} \indexcode{pwz}
\indexcode{qwz} \indexcode{rwz} \indexcode{swz} \indexcode{twz}
\indexcode{uwz} \indexcode{vwz} \indexcode{wwz} \indexcode{xwz}
\indexcode{ywz} \indexcode{zwz} \indexcode{axz} \indexcode{bxz}
\indexcode{cxz} \indexcode{dxz} \indexcode{exz} \indexcode{fxz}
\indexcode{gxz} \indexcode{hxz} \indexcode{ixz} \indexcode{jxz}
\lipsum[5-8]

\backmatter
\printindex[book]
\printindex[code]

\end{document}
```

When I typeset this, I get a PDF with 9 pages. Pages 2 and 3 correctly have "CHAPTER 1. CALL ME ISHMAEL" in their header. Page 4's header is correctly blank. Pages 5 and 6 incorrectly have "CHAPTER 1. CALL ME ISHMAEL" in their header (when I expected to see "INDEX"). Pages 8 and 9 incorrectly have "CHAPTER 1. CALL ME ISHMAEL" in their header (when I expected to see "INDEX OF CODE SAMPLES").

---

If I change the MCE to end like this:

```
%...
\backmatter
\chaptermark{Index}
\printindex[book]
\chaptermark{Index of code samples}
\printindex[code]

\end{document}
```

then I see the correct "INDEX" header on page 5 and the correct "INDEX OF CODE SAMPLES" header on pages 8 and 9. But now page 6 incorrectly has "INDEX OF CODE SAMPLES" in its header (when I expected to see "INDEX")!

What should I do to get the correct headers on all pages of my indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\printindex` prints a `\chapter*`, it suffices to issue `\clearpage` *before* setting the header and printing the index:

```
%...
\backmatter

\clearpage
\chaptermark{Index}
\printindex[book]

\clearpage
\chaptermark{Index of code samples}
\printindex[code]

\end{document}
```

This way the page headers are set on a new page - the same page as where the index printing starts.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This definitely works and I will start using it; but I can't help wondering if there's a more "batteries included" way to do it, given that I'm already using `imakeidx`'s `\makeindex[title=...]`. Like, is there really no way to tell `imakeidx` that I want it to use that same `title` for the title of the index? :P

Comment: @Quuxplusone: The index is created with an external program. You can [update `\printindex` to print the header as a new, mandatory argument](https://pastebin.com/2b5kPqca).