# BibLaTeX incompatibility with titlesec

Tags: biblatex, titlesec

First of all: I know about [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310135/incompatibility-between-biblatex-and-titlesec) question and about the statement in the BibLaTeX documentation:

> The titlesec package redefines user-level document division commands such as \chapter or \section. This approach is not compatible with internal command changes applied by the biblatex refsection and refsegment option settings described in § 3.1.2.1.

In contrast to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310135/incompatibility-between-biblatex-and-titlesec), I cannot see any problem in my document. Nevertheless, I ask myself if there could be other problems I didn't see (until now).

So my question is the following:
Will I run into problems if I use biblatex and titlesec like this:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
natbib=false,
maxbibnames=100,
maxcitenames=3,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature/lit.bib}
% ...
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\huge\center\bf}%
    {\large\mdseries CHAPTER \thechapter}%
    {0cm}{}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0ex}{8ex}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{.75em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[.]
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\itshape}{}{0pt}{}[.]
% ...
\printbibliography
```

As stated in the BibLaTeX documentation, the incompatibility affects options refsection and refsegment. I do not use these options. Do I have to expect any unwanted side effects?

Comment: Well, if you don't use (automatically generated) `refsection`s or `refsegment`s, you should be fine from a technical point of view. **But** `titlesec` alters the output of section/chapter headings and headers and footers, `biblatex` might not give the exact output you expect. You need to double-check the headers and footers on the bibliography pages generated by `biblatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three points in `biblatex.sty` where `\chapter`, `\section` and friends are patched.

1. To enable the `refsection` option which automatically starts a new `refsection` each `\chapter`, `\section`, ... The default value is `refsection=none` in which case nothing needs to be patched.
2. To enable the `refsegment` option which automatically starts a new `refsegment` each `\chapter`, `\section`, ... The default value is `refsegment=none` in which case nothing needs to be patched.
3. To enable the `citereset` option which automatically resets all citation trackers each `\chapter`, `\section`, ... The default value is `citereset=none` in which case nothing needs to be patched.

See §3.1.1 *Load-time Options*, pp. 51-52 for more details on these options.

So the bit of the documentation you quote should read

> The `titlesec` package redefines user-level document division commands such
>   as `\chapter` or `\section`  This approach is not compatible with internal command changes applied by the `biblatex` `refsection`, `refsegment` and `citereset` option settings described in §3.1.2.1.

This will be the case in the next release: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/77141cd205df6348bb7c203705f4bcc535026d27.

From a technical point of view this is all you need to worry about for proper functionality of the package. If you don't use any of the three options, you should be fine.

**But** `titlesec` has influence not only on section and chapter headings, but also on headers and footers. It could be that `biblatex`'s default headings don't play nicely along with `titlesec` definitions as expected. So you should definitely check the output of headers, footers and headings on the bibliography pages created by `biblatex`.

Comment: For headers and footers I additionally use the fancyhdr package. It is loaded between biblatex and titlesec. Possibly, it would be a good idea to place fancyhdr after titlesec in order to overwrite titlesec's headers and footers?

Comment: @lukasl1991 That might work, but the effects of loading order depends on the exact implementation of the packages. So you really need to double-check that the output is as you expect.

Comment: If you use `titlesec`, why not use `titleps` rather than `fancyhdr`. It's generally so much simpler to use…

Comment: I'm customizing a LaTeX template provided by my university for my purposes. The template used fancyhdr and titlesec (and BibTeX instead of BibLaTex).

Comment: @moewe What exactly do you mean with double-check? Simply pay attention if the output looks as I expect?

Comment: @lukasl1991 Yes, exactly that. In this particular case you want to pay close attention to headings, headers, and footers.