# Easy fix for Biblatex, Titlesec, and citereset?

Tags: biblatex, titlesec

I have read through [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412823/biblatex-incompatibility-with-titlesec), [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310135/incompatibility-between-biblatex-and-titlesec), and a handful of others (as well as section 1.5.5 in the `biblatex` manual). I know that `titlesec` redefines things that `biblatex` uses for the `citereset`. Is there an easy fix to this?

Here is a MWE for `biblatex` and verbose style:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit,largestsep]{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose,citepages=omit,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
@book{Book1,
   author    = {John Smith},
   title     = {A Good Book},
   publisher = {Good Publishing House},
   address   = {NY},
   year      = {2020}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

%%% TEMP
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
     {\normalsize\rmfamily\center}
     {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter}}
     {0pt}
     {\MakeUppercase{#1}}
%%%   
\null\vfill
I like good books.\footcite[6]{Book1} But now a short ref.\footcite[10]{Book1}

\chapter{New Chapter}
\null\vfill
This should be a full citation.\footcite[15]{Book1}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For the first citations:

[image]

For the citation in the new chapter, this gives:

[image: wrong cite]

What is interesting, is that the `citereset` problem only occurs if I uses the `titleformat` command. Just including `titlesec` does not cause a problem.

What is also interesting, is that `biblatex-chicago` is able to *somewhat* get around this issue. Here is a MWE for `biblatex-chicago`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[explicit,largestsep]{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{customstyles.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{tdict}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[noibid,backend=biber,notes,isbn=false,shorthandfull,shorthandfirst,inheritshorthand=true,citereset=chapter]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
@book{Book1,
   author    = {John Smith},
   title     = {A Good Book},
   publisher = {Good Publishing House},
   address   = {NY},
   year      = {2020}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

%%% TEMP
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
     {\normalsize\rmfamily\center}
     {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter}}
     {0pt}
     {\MakeUppercase{#1}}
%%%

\null\vfill
I like good books.\footcite[6]{Book1} But now a short ref.\footcite[10]{Book1}

\chapter{New Chapter}
\null\vfill
This should be a full citation.\footcite[15]{Book1}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

First citations:

[image: bib-chic1]

Citation after new chapter:

[image: bib-chic2]

In the first subsequent citation, it is author. Then in the new chapter, it is author-title. So `biblatex-chicago` can tell the difference.

I know that all I have to do is issue the `citereset` command after every `\chapter` command. So this is my failsafe. However, I would like a solution that does not require manual work (I am trying to put this into a package).

Thanks!

**EDIT**
After further testing, the behavior of `biblatex-chicago` is simply the same behavior of citing author-title on a new page. So the `\chapter` is not doing anything different. So the `biblatex-chicago` example above is not helpful. I have removed the `biblatex-chicago` tag.

Comment: Where is the `fullbibrefs` key defined? I obtain an error message.

Comment: If `biblatex-chicago` is loaded by your package, you could just hook into the `\chapter` command to make the `\citereset` automatic.

Comment: @Bernard whoops, sorry, I had a different style at first, then changed to `verbose` in my MWE. You can remove the `fullbibrefs`. I have updated above.

Comment: @AlanMunn what do you mean? I do use the `\chapter` command with `biblatex-chicago`. I just used that as an example that the `\citereset` hook is performed at least on some values. Although now that I think about it, it might just be the regular behavior of `biblatex-chicago` on a new page. The problem is with regular `biblatex` and `titlesec` where the `\chapter` command DOES NOT citereset correctly.

Comment: @Bernard has implemented my suggestion in his answer. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn: didn't know you  suggested  this solution . Great minds think  together … ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem  is mentioned in the documentation, §1.5.5 Incompatible Packages. A solution consists in replacing this option key with the corresponding command placed in the `\titleformat` command:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit,largestsep]{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose, citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
@book{Book1,
   author = {John Smith},
   title = {A Good Book},
   publisher = {Good Publishing House},
   address = {NY},
   year = {2020}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

%%% TEMP
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
     {\normalsize\rmfamily\center}
     {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter}}
     {0pt}
     {\citereset\MakeUppercase{#1}}
%%%
\null\vfill
I like good books.\footcite[6]{Book1} But now a short ref.\footcite[10]{Book1}

\chapter{New Chapter}
\null\vfill
This should be a full citation.\footcite[15]{Book1}

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! That was indeed easy. I should have thought of that!