# Header issue in bibliography using biblatex and titlesec

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, titlesec

I am in the process of writing my thesis with latex and I have a header issue in the bibliography section.
I use titlesec package for the header and biblatex for both bibliography and a publication list appearing later in the text.

Here is a MWE of my problem, the headers in the publication list sections are fine but "REFERENCES" is added in the header and footer of the bibliography and I cannot find how to get this correctly.

```
\documentclass[
    openany,
    twoside,
    12pt]
    {report}

\begin{filecontents}{exempleref.bib}
@book{jane1980,
  author    = "Jane Doe",
  title     = "Matrix Computations",
  edition   = "4th Edition",
  publisher = "The Johns Hopkins University Press",
  address   = "Baltimore, Maryland",
  year      = "2013",
  }

  @Article{doe2017,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

    @Article{doe2016,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "First Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

    @Article{doe2015,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "Previous Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

    @Article{doe2014,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "Another Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

    @Article{doe2013,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "Prequel to Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

    @Article{doe2012,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "Prequel to prequel to Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

    @Article{doe2011,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "Before Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

    @Article{doe2010,
  Author    = "John Doe",
  Title     = "Introduction to Latex Minimal Working Ewample (MWE) First Edition",
  Journal = "Great LateX Journal",
  Year      = "2017",
  Number = "3",
  Pages = "1-23",
  Volume = {1},
  }

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=16cm,
    paperheight=24cm]
    {geometry} 

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[
    natbib=true,
    style=nature, %bibliography style
    backend=bibtex8,
    defernumbers, %Will put new reference number for publication list
    sorting = none, %sort bibliography by in text citation number
    firstinits=true,    %turn first and middle names as intials
    doi=false,      %no doi 
    isbn=false, %no isbn field
    url=false]      % no url in bibliography
    {biblatex}

\addbibresource{exempleref.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%change the name of the bibliography section to "References"
  bibliography = {References},
}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{% %should fix the heading but is inneficient
  \section*{#1}
  \markboth{}{}
  }

\usepackage[
    pagestyles] %option allow to change page header 
    {titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\bf\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bf} %change chapter N to N. chapter title
\newpagestyle{mystyle} %page style for whole document
{\sethead[\thepage][][\thechapter .~\chaptertitle]{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
}
\newpagestyle{bibstyle} %page style for bibliography
{\sethead[\thepage][][\thechapter .~\chaptertitle]{}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter {First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-1]
\cite{jane1980}
\lipsum[2-2]
\cite{doe2010,doe2011,doe2012,doe2013,doe2014,doe2015,doe2016,doe2017}


\pagestyle{bibstyle}  %use the header style for the bibliography
\printbibheading[title = {References}, heading = bibnumbered] %print bibliography title
\printbibliography[heading=none] %print the bibligraphy

\pagestyle{mystyle} %recover document heading style
\begin{refsection} %new section for separated publication list
\printbibheading[title = {Publications list}, heading = bibnumbered]
\nocite{*}
\section {Articles}
        \printbibliography[type=article, prefixnumbers={A.}, heading=none]
\section {Book}
        \printbibliography[type=book, prefixnumbers={B.}, heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

This is the resulted output where I would like the red circled "REFERENCES" to be removed:

[image: Wrong header]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think I had a very similar problem last year. I solved it thanks to @egreg's answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89884/bibliography-and-headers-with-titleps-and-biblatex). For the `report class`, try adding this  to your preamble after `biblatex` is loaded: `\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\chapter*{#1}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the setting for the heading `bibliography`, but then you use `heading=bibnumbered`, so you will have to change that as well. Probably to

```
\defbibheading{bibnumbered}[\refname]{\chapter{#1}}
```

BTW You should not have to use empty `\markboth{}{}`, it should be enough to leave it out altogether.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot! This worked like a charm!
(I also removed `\markboth{}{}`)